# Generating a PDF file from a PowerPoint file with Excel and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to generate a PDF file from a PowerPoint file. This should all be done from clicking a button in an Excel file with a VBA script. So far I have managed to write the code below. It opens the PowerPoint file correctly, but also displays the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

```
strPath = "Q:\X\Test.pptx"

Set objApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
objApp.Visible = True 'False or True

Set wbToRun = objApp.Presentations.Open(strPath)

wbToRun.ExportAsFixedFormat  "<Q:\X\1.pdf>", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst, ppPrintOutputBuildSlides, msoFalse, , , ,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False

objApp.DisplayAlerts = False
wbToRun.Close
objApp.Quit
```

Hope you are able to help on where I went wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: This one:

`wbToRun.ExportAsFixedFormat  "<Q:\X\1.pdf>", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst, ppPrintOutputBuildSlides, msoFalse, , , ,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your errors. The following solution worked for me. Make sure you have enabled your reference to the Microsoft Powerpoint Object Library.

```
Sub ppttest5()

Dim savePath As String
Dim AppPowerPoint
Dim wbToRun

Set AppPowerPoint = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
 'Location of saved file
savePathFN = "C:\mydirb\test.pdf" 'change as per your path
AppPowerPoint.Visible = True

Set wbToRun = AppPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\mydirb\Test.pptx") 'change location of file path

wbToRun.SaveAs savePathFN, ppSaveAsPDF
wbToRun.Close


AppPowerPoint.Quit
Set OpenPresentation = Nothing
Set AppPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! However, still getting an error: "System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809) The parameter is incorrect."

Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @user3527005 I have uploaded a zipped file which contains sample pptx file, code file and generated pdf file. Please check at your end maintaining same or similar directory structure and also check reference to your version of Power Point Object Library. I also checked the program running with `ExportAsFixedFormat`, it gives Type Mismatch error on this very line. This is one of the commonly occurring error and there are many suggestions to overcome this error My dropbox reference is<https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tage2z1gxxs9mh/55157774.7z?dl=0> .My efforts on some tries could not workout.

Comment: @user3527005 Regarding  "System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809)" one possible reason among others could be mis-spelled shapes names. I suggested my tried out method to you after some references where after getting Type Mismatch on `ExportAsFixedFormat` following all precautions like correct variables and references to all optional parameters problem could not be resolved but `SaveasPDF` succeeded.

Comment: Thank you so much. Still getting an error. Something I have tried which does work is:

`wbToRun.SaveAs "Q:\X\1.pdf"`

So it is basically the ", ppSaveAsPDF" part that throws an error. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @user3527005 could you try my macro file adjusting Power Point Object library as per your version in VBE Tools -References and do you still get error.I have no problem generating pdf with suggested code on my 2016 version system. I have also included the generated pdf file also in the zipped folder. You may slso try on someone else computer , because Systems errors are also generated in case of corrupt Excel files.

Comment: @user3527005 The only other alternative is `ExportAsFixedFormat` .Does that by chance works for you. I do not think there is any error in that part of your code.